# Problem adding caption with siunitx

Tags: beamer, siunitx

I am using latex/beamer(texlive) to compile a document and I am getting an error. Apparently it has something to do with `siunitx` package. Here is a minimum working example.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage{ragged2e} 
\usefonttheme{serif}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{font = sl}
\sisetup{detect-all}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty %supress navigation bars
%\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newcommand{\sym}[1]{\rlap{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]\centering
\def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}
\caption{OLS regressions for two measures of internet availability}
\begin{tabular}{l*{2}{S}}
\toprule
                &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(1)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(2)}\\
                &\multicolumn{1}{c}{Vote share low-budget   parties}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Vote share low-budget parties}\\
\midrule
Internet density    &       0.013\sym{***}&           -         \\
                &     [0.003]         &                     \\
\% Internet         &           -         &       0.012\sym{***}\\
                &                     &     [0.001]         \\
\% Voters affiliated to the party&       0.011\sym{***}&       0.012\sym{***}\\
                &     [0.002]         &     [0.002]         \\
\midrule Geographic Controls &       {Yes}         &       {Yes}         \\
Act. Controls       &       {Yes}         &       {Yes}         \\
Demographic Controls&       {Yes}         &       {Yes}         \\
\midrule
Observations        &\multicolumn{1}{c}{5558}         &\multicolumn{1}{c}{5558}            \\
\(R^{2}\)           &\multicolumn{1}{c}{0.371}         &\multicolumn{1}{c}{0.384}         \\
\bottomrule
\multicolumn{3}{l}{\footnotesize \sym{*} \(p<0.05\), \sym{**} \(p<0.01\),     \sym{***} \(p<0.001\)}\\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

I get the following error.

[image]

I call it table2.tex and use \input{table2}. Many thanks for any help.

EDIT

@JosephWright is right, this example works. The problem appears when I add the adjust box.

```
\begin{frame}
\centering
\adjustbox{max height=\dimexpr\textheight-5.5cm\relax,
       max width=\textwidth}{
\input{table2}
}

\end{frame}
```

EDIT 2

I managed to adjust the size of the table by just playing with the font size.

```
\begin{frame}

\centering
\scriptsize
\input{table2}

\end{frame}
```

Here is a nice blog post that teaches you how to produce nice tables in latex using siunitx.

http://www.jwe.cc/2012/03/stata-latex-tables-estout

Comment: The error I get is about the invalid input `-`: you have cells only containing a `-`  which `siunitx` won't like and which work fine when replaced with `{--}`.

Comment: Hi @JosephWright, thanks for your reply. I still get the same error after replacing - by {--}.

Comment: Did you run _exactly_ the demo you have in the question? If so, can you add `\listfiles` and edit the `File list` that appears in the `.log` file into the question.

Comment: @JosephWright many thanks for your help. You are right, the example runs. I realised the problem happens when I use the \adjustbox. Please see my edit.

Comment: (Follow edit) Do you have a `table` environment inside the secondary file? The `beamer` class redefines the float environments, but even so trying to put one inside a box is a bad idea.

Comment: Yes, I have a table environment in the secondary file. What would you suggest to adjust the table size to the frame.

Comment: And when I do not include the \caption the \adjustbox works just fine. Would there be a workaround to insert the caption.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because solved according to "Edit 2"